# Почему слайдер дергается и как можно решить эту проблему?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

подскажите как решить такую проблему: нужен слайдер центральный слайд которого был бы `~800px`, а остальные (2 сбоку) имели ширину поменьше и были половинчатыми(см. codepen), ну и находились вертикально по центру родителя, в принципе, эта задача решена, но проблема в другом. **У меня сейчас на слайдере создается эффект захождения вперед и резный возврат назад.**(эффект дергания). Если сделать все изображения одинаковой ширины - никакой проблемы нет, все плавно и красиво. Есть ли вообще вариант решения этой проблемы на этом слайдере slick? Или подкиньте готовы вариант, если у вас имеется линки на них.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbjWez

Comment: Slick не умеет определять центральный слайд и присваивать ему бОльшую ширину динамически. Возможно, вам подойдёт этот слайдер: http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/

Answer (score 2):

Происходит резкая смена ширины фото и резкая смена `transform`(т.к. она относительно ширины, а ширина меняется резко). Добавила `transition`(в самом конце `css`) - эта смена стала происходить плавно. Можете попробовать разные задержки на `transition`, возможно получится желаемый результат:

```js
$('.main__slider').slick({
    arrows: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    centerPadding: '0',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    focusOnSelect: true
  });
```

```css
.slick-slide {
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}
.slick-slide.slick-center {
  width: 600px;
}
.slick-slide.slick-center::after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.slick-slide::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0.65;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slick-track{
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.slick-slide{
  transition: width .5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
<div class="main__slider">
   <div>
        <img src="http://worldoftanksblitz.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/wallpaper_7_ipad2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
   <div>
        <img src="http://worldoftanksblitz.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/wallpaper_7_ipad2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
     <div>
          <img src="http://worldoftanksblitz.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/wallpaper_7_ipad2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
   <div>
        <img src="http://worldoftanksblitz.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/wallpaper_7_ipad2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
```